# Creating specified UIColor in iOS

Tags: ios, uicolor

I have to create the text color as shown in the picture, can someone help me with the RGB values for the specified colour.

[image: Creating blue color in ios]

I tried the following code

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(102.0/255.0) green:(204.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
```

But i am not able to get the exact color which is expected.

Any help on this will be appreciable

Comment: I suggest you try google.

Comment: I tried the following code, [UIColor colorWithRed:(102.0/255.0) green:(204.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];   But i am not able to get the exact uicolour. Any help will be appreciable

Comment: please do not use : [UIColor colorWithRed:(102.0/255.0) green:(204.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

Instead use the actual values like : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5058 green:0.7725 blue:0.9176 alpha:1.0];

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the DigitalColor Meter app in MacOS to find the RGB values.
All you need to do is open the app and then just put your cursor on that text or area whose RGB value you wish to find.

DigitalColor Meter : Either you can get using the search bar or Applications/Utitlies/DigitalColor Meter

And then please do not use : [UIColor colorWithRed:(102.0/255.0) green:(204.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

Instead use the actual values like : [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5058 green:0.7725 blue:0.9176 alpha:1.0];

[image: Finding RGB values using DigitalColor Meter app in MacOS]

Comment: He won't be able to find it if you don't say that it's in utilities.

Comment: yes, either you can get using the search bar or Applications/Utitlies/DigitalColor Meter

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
[UIColor CyanColor]
```

or

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:RespectiveValue.f/255.0f green:RespectiveValue.0f/255.0f blue:RespectiveValue.f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take UILabel in xib . After the selection go to Show the atrributeinspector. There you can find the color. Then click on that. It displays

[image].

Drag and drop the search icon on the text which you have posted in your post .

[image]

Then click on the secondone. It displays the below image .

Comment: What exactly is this?

Comment: You can know the rgb values of any text or image ..... using this procedure